# Django models range from to

Tags: django, django-models

Hello In my model I have

```
age_from = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Age min.')
age_to = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Age max')
```

I would like to have age to to be greater or equal to age from

Comment: your question isn't very clear

Comment: So you want to add a constraint to your model? What if a value is `NULL`?

Comment: It's not obvious what your actual task is? Eventually you might be better served by [RangeFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#range-fields), if your DB is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Ty @Willem Van Onsen :)

Comment: The object must be null it's optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify some constraints on your model in Django, but enforcing these (for example in the ORM) is quite hard. Below two approaches.

## By using the `.clean()` method

You can add a constraint to a model, by overriding the `clean(..)` function, but note that these are - by default - *not* enforced at the model/ORM layer, `Form`s (which are a common way to create/update) values, however will call the `clean(..)` function, and thus raise an exception.

For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def clean(self):
        a1 = self.age_from
        a2 = self.age_to
        if a1 is not None and a2 is not None and a1 > a2:
            raise ValidationError('age_from should be less than or equal to age_to')
        super().clean()
```

So this checks that if both columns are non-`None`, that `age_from` is less than or equal to `age_to`. If not, it will raise an error.

## With `django-db-constraints`

You can also enforce the constraints at the database level, given your database system supports this, for example with the [**`django-db-constraints`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/rapilabs/django-db-constraints) package.

You can then add a constraint like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_constraints = {
            'age_check': 'CHECK (age_from IS NULL OR age_to IS NULL OR age_from <= age_to)',
        }
```